# c# sort collection based on enum

Tags: c#, sorting, enums

I would like to sort `ObservableCollection<myClass>` which, except for the other things, contains the `enum` property such as following:

```
public IP_Enums.ExportType ExportType { get; set; }
```

Where the structure of enum looks like following:

```
    public enum ExportType
    {
        A1,
        A2,
        B1,
        B2,
        B3,
        C1,
        C2,
        D1,
        D2
    }
```

The problem I have is, that Export types under my `ObservableCollection<myClass>` are not in an order (as you can see in the enum definition), but like this e.g.:

```
[0].ExportType = ExportType.B2
[1].ExportType = ExportType.A1
[2].ExportType = ExportType.D2
[3].ExportType = ExportType.A1
```

I would like to sort my collection based on this ExportType, but I am not quite sure how to do it (as I have [A-Z] character followed by digit [0-9].

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: I want to order the same collection, as I am afterwards flushing all elements into a XML file.

Comment: `yourCollection.Orderby(x => x.ExportType);` is that what you want?

Comment: I have already tried `myCollection.OrderBy()` but it did not order collection by any means

Comment: @stuartd I am not trying to change enum order, I am trying to order all items under my collection in an ascending order - from A1 to D2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new `ObservableCollection<myClass>` collection sorted by the `ExportType` values:

```
ObservableCollection<myClass> collection = ...;
collection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>(collection.OrderBy(item => item.ExportType));
```

Comment: It's strange, but when I create new collection (not trying to order already existing collection) this suddenly works. Could you please explain why is this?

Comment: Does `myClass` implement `IComparable<myClass>`?

Comment: No, it implements `IEquatable<myClass>`